# Android requestSingleUpdate vs requestLocationUpdates battery consumption

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I have an application that logs the user location every minute. Till today I was using requestLocationUpdates():

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, gpsLocationListener)
```

and every minute (almost) I receive an update and log it in the onLocationChanged() method.
Today I found out that also requestSingleUpdate is available:

```
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, gpsLocationListener, null )
```

In this second case once I receive the location in onLocationChanged(), I start an handler postDelay and after one minute I run again the requestSingleUpdate(). During this minute interval when no locations updates are requested the gps icon on the top right disappears.

My question is: can the second solution reduce the battery consumption? Thank you